# Looping in batches without repeating

Tags: javascript, loops

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm new to programming and trying to write a loop that processes things in batches.

```
const totalPages = 13;
const batchSize = 3;
const startFrom = 0;
let processed = startFrom || 1;

while (processed < totalPages) {
    let start = processed; 
    let end = Math.min(start + batchSize, totalPages); 
    console.log(`processing batch: ${start}-${end}`); 
    processed = end;
}
```

Outputs:

```
processing batch: 1-4
processing batch: 4-7
processing batch: 7-10
processing batch: 10-13
```

However the start and end are not what I expect, I need it to be:

```
processing batch: 1-3
processing batch: 4-6
processing batch: 7-9
processing batch: 10-12
processing batch: 13-13
```

Comment: `start + batchSize` is `4` when you have `start = 1` and `batchSize = 3`. If you need it to *not* be `4` then that formula is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start out with `processed` equal to 1, but that is not true: at that moment you have not "processed" anything yet, so it should be 0. On the other hand `start` should not be made equal to `processed`, but to one more -- as it is the *next* one after those that have already been processed.

Alter the other expressions accordingly:

```js
const totalPages = 13;
const batchSize = 3;
const startFrom = 0;
let processed = startFrom;

while (processed < totalPages) {
    let start = processed + 1; 
    let end = Math.min(processed + batchSize, totalPages); 
    console.log(`processing batch: ${start}-${end}`); 
    processed = end;
}
```

It is more common to use a `for` loop for this. You could also have the parameters as function parameters. Finally, `startFrom` is maybe not a good name for that variable, as it suggests a number of an item (starting from 1). I would suggest `skip`, so that 0 means nothing should be skipped:

```js
function printBatches(totalPages, batchSize, skip=0) {
    for (let processed = skip; processed < totalPages; processed += batchSize) {
        let start = processed + 1;
        let end = Math.min(processed + batchSize, totalPages); 
        console.log(`processing batch: ${start}-${end}`); 
    }
}

printBatches(13, 3);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation and the `for` alternative approach.